# MySql query gives different output from phpmyadmin, here group_concat not work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any mistake in mysql query, anyone help please.
Thanks!!

DATABASE Table (Below)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_sales
    (`plantcode` varchar(200), `materialcode` varchar(200), `nrv` varchar(200) ,`monthyear` date)
;   
INSERT INTO tbl_sales
    (`plantcode`, `materialcode`, `nrv`, `monthyear`)
VALUES
    ('9001','800000006','210','2015-02-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','220','2015-02-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','350','2015-02-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','100','2015-03-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','421.00','2015-04-01'),
    ('9001','400000100','257','2015-05-01'),
    ('9001','400000100','233','2015-07-01'),
    ('9002','800000006','710','2016-02-01'),
    ('9002','800000006','325','2016-06-01')
;
```

I create query for dynamic row convert into dynamic column by date(monthyear field).

```
SELECT plantcode,materialcode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(monthyear,''%b %y'')= ''',
          DATE_FORMAT(monthyear,'%b %y'),
                       ''' THEN nrv ELSE 0 END) AS '' ',
                       DATE_FORMAT(monthyear, '%b %y'),'"' 
                     )  
                  ORDER BY monthyear)
    from tbl_sales
    GROUP BY materialcode
```

when i use this query in phpmyadmin, it shows optput like below

[Output From PHPMyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPB6H.jpg)

And i need actual output like below:

```
Plantcode   Materialcode    Feb 2015    Mar 2015    Apr 2015    May 2015
9001        800000006       780         100         421.00      257
```

GUYS I Done with my custom code.... check below...

```
$qry1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(`monthyear`) FROM `tbl_sales` ORDER BY `monthyear` ASC");
$rcount = mysql_num_rows($qry1);
$sql2 = "SELECT `plantcode`,`materialcode`, ";
$dynamic_column = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry1)) 
{
    $dynamic_column[] = $rows['monthyear'];
    $sql2 .= "SUM(IF(`monthyear` = '{$rows['monthyear']}',`nrv`,0)) AS '{$rows['monthyear']}'";
    if ($rcount > 1) 
    {
        $sql2 .=',';
    }
    $rcount--;
}

$sql2 .= " FROM `tbl_sales` WHERE `plantcode`='9001' AND `monthyear` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-06-30' GROUP BY `materialcode`,`year` ORDER BY `year`,`monthyear`,`dsapcode` ASC ";
```

Check below image output screen....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSViE.jpg)

Comment: `9001 800000006` does not have data in May 2015.

Comment: i have more data in my table , here i explain as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, cause you use `materialcode` for `group by`, so `plantcode` in result makes no sense.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c347ae/4)

**MySQL 5.6**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_sales
    (`plantcode` varchar(200), `materialcode` varchar(200), `nrv` varchar(200) ,`monthyear` date)
;   
INSERT INTO tbl_sales
    (`plantcode`, `materialcode`, `nrv`, `monthyear`)
VALUES
    ('9001','800000006','210','2015-02-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','220','2015-02-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','350','2015-02-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','100','2015-03-01'),
    ('9001','800000006','421.00','2015-04-01'),
    ('9001','400000100','257','2015-05-01'),
    ('9001','400000100','233','2015-07-01'),
    ('9002','800000006','710','2016-02-01'),
    ('9002','800000006','325','2016-06-01')
;
```

**Query**:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(monthyear = ''',
      monthyear,
      ''', nrv, 0)) AS `',
      DATE_FORMAT(monthyear,'%b %y'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_sales;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT plantcode, materialcode, ', @sql, ' FROM tbl_sales GROUP BY materialcode');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c347ae/4)**:

```
| plantcode | materialcode | Feb 15 | Mar 15 | Apr 15 | May 15 | Jul 15 | Feb 16 | Jun 16 |
|-----------|--------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      9001 |    400000100 |      0 |      0 |      0 |    257 |    233 |      0 |      0 |
|      9001 |    800000006 |    780 |    100 |    421 |      0 |      0 |    710 |    325 |
```

Comment: Thanks!!!this query is working fine with sqlfiddle, but not working in phpmyadmin, dear is there any possible way to using php code?

Comment: I believe there is a way to use php to achieve this. However I can only give you a sql answer. :-(

Comment: You are right man. But i am php programmer and i want monthyear wise sales record so i am very confuse what can i do? this is very typical task without pivot query. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Amit You can try to solve it by yourself first with php, if you can not make  it, then you can ask a new question on SO for php solution.